# cairo_show_text display only one column

Tags: c, overlay, cairo

I try to display one text in a PNG image using CAIRO.

My problem here is that in the "for" loop, cairo display only one colum and not the entire string, ex: 3 2 1
my small code:

```
char  sets2 [100] ;
            for (size_t i=0; i < match->nb_set; i++)
            {
            char  chaine  = joueur->sets[i] ;
            sprintf(sets2 , "%d", chaine);
            printf("%s ", sets2);  // This print 3 2 1
            cairo_move_to(cr, 250, 120);
            cairo_show_text(cr, sets2); // this display in the image one colum the overlayed number
            }
```

Is this my for loop or cairo displaying like this ?
Really thank you in advance if you can help,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the x axys on each iteration, otherwise you end up printing all the digits at the same position, something like:

```
int x = 250, y = 120;
char sets2[100];

for (size_t i=0; i < match->nb_set; i++)
{
    char  chaine  = joueur->sets[i] ;
    sprintf(sets2 , "%d", chaine);
    printf("%s ", sets2);
    cairo_move_to(cr, x, y);
    cairo_show_text(cr, sets2);
    x += 10; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.